# How to load more data in android list view using Custom Adapter at bottom on scroll

Tags: android, listview, load, scrollview, custom-adapter

I have tried this but on every new request it loads new data and replace old data.need help 
I am getting data from web service and have to show in list view using custom adapter.but on loading more it dosent work

```
  public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
            private int visibleThreshold = 0;
            private int currentPage = 0;
            private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
            private boolean loading = true;
            private int startingPageIndex = 0;
            public EndlessScrollListener() {
            }

            public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
                this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
            }
            public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
                this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
                this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
                this.currentPage = startPage;
            }
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount)) {
                    this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
                    this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                    if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                        this.loading = true;
                    }
                }
                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                        currentPage++;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading
                        && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
            public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you use something like adapter.setData(data) instead of adapter.addData(data)

Answer (score 0):

```
int lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
if(!loading && lastVisibleItem == totalItemCount) {
    onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, PAGE_SIZE);
    loading = true;
}
```

and don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating data in adapter.